# Does the IClientValidator support input file?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-core-2.1

**Edit**

I found that the problem is that View Components are unable to have an @section ([see ViewComponent and @Section #2910](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2910) ) so adding custom client-side validation using the unobtrusive library seems imposible (or very complex). Moreover, the inability of including the required javascript into a View Component makes me regret of following this approach to modularize my app in the first place...

---

I am learning to make custom validation attributes with client-side support. I was able to implement a custom validator for a string property and it works pretty well, but when I tried to make one for input file it doesn't work (i.e. when I select a file in my computer, the application doesn't display the validation messages. The server-side validation works. Here is some code that shows my implementation.

The class of the model

```
public class UploadPanelModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } //Raw HTML with the panel description
    [FileType(type:  "application/pdf")]
    [FileSize(maxSize: 5000000)]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
    public ModalModel Modal { get; set; } //Only used if the Upload panel uses a modal.
```

The validator

```
public class FileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private long _MaxSize { get; set; }
    public FileSizeAttribute (long maxSize)
    {
        _MaxSize = maxSize;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        UploadPanelModel panel = (UploadPanelModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        return (panel.File==null || panel.File.Length <= _MaxSize) ?  ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult(GetFileSizeErrorMessage(_MaxSize));
    }
    private string GetFileSizeErrorMessage(long maxSize)
    {
        double megabytes = maxSize / 1000000.0;
        return $"El archivo debe pesar menos de {megabytes}MB";
    }
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if(context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-filesize", GetFileSizeErrorMessage(_MaxSize));
        var maxSize = _MaxSize.ToString();
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-filesize-maxsize", maxSize);         
    }
    private bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The javascript in the Razor View

```
@section Scripts{
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.addMethod('filesize',
        function (value, element, params) {
            var size = $((params[0]).val()).size(),
                maxSize = params[1];
            if (size < maxSize) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('filesize',
        ['maxSize'],
        function (options) {
            var element = $(options.form).find('input#File')[0];
            options.rules['filesize'] = [element, options.params['maxSize']];
            options.messages['filesize'] = options.message;
        }
    );
</script>
```

I always return false in the javascript method to force the application to show the validation error regardless the chosen file, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addMethod()` function will be throwing an error because `params[0]` is not a jQuery object and has no `.val()` (you also have the `$` in the wrong place). You would need to use

```
var size = params[0].files[0].size;
```

However I suggest you write you scripts as

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('filesize', ['maxsize'], function (options) {
    options.rules['filesize'] = { maxsize: options.params.maxsize };
    if (options.message) {
        options.messages['filesize'] = options.message;
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("filesize", function (value, element, param) {
    if (value === "") {
        return true;
    }
    var maxsize = parseInt(param.maxsize);
    if (element.files != undefined && element.files[0] != undefined && element.files[0].size != undefined) {
        var filesize = parseInt(element.files[0].size);
        return filesize <= maxsize ;
    }
    return true; // in case browser does not support HTML5 file API
});
```

Comment: Hi there. I tried to use your script, but it didn't work. It seems that the client-side validation does not work for input file...

Comment: Of course it does - I have both a `[FileType]` and `[FileSize]` attribute working perfectly. Use your browser to step throw the code and debug it.

Comment: o.o ok. I will try again and report the results tomorrow.

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing the server-side validation (which work perfectly) with the client-side validation. The app sends the file to the server, but it should validate it before sending it.

Comment: I am not confusing anything. I have a library of over 50 validation attributes that validate server **and client** side

Comment: Roger that!  :).

Comment: See also edit - I just copied you code, should be `maxsize` (all lower case)

Comment: Just to prove it works, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VZENRZ). Not I just hard coded the file input including the `data-val-` attributes (used 100 bytes for the file size so you will see the client side error when you submit, and if you change that to a large number so that it does submit, you will see a different result)

Comment: Thanks for posting your example. I notice that you used .NET framework instead of ASP.NET Core and HttpPostedFileBase instead of IFormFile in the server. I don't know if these factors are influencing the result. Nevertheless, today I will try to make this work and report back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180300/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-renato-sanhueza).